# Parse error: near "autoincrement": syntax error - SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, syntax-error, auto-increment, parse-error

I get a syntax error near `AUTOINCREMENT`. What is the cause of this error?

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE department (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (leader) REFERENCES person(id)
);
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[According to SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1) you have to declare either a `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` column to achieve that.

Answer (score 10):

In SQLite you need not to specify AUTOINCREMENT if you are specifying a column as Primary Key...

Answer (score 1):

SQLite AUTOINCREMENT :  You Should Avoid Using It

Unless you create a table specifying the `WITHOUT ROWID` option, you get an implicit auto increment column called `rowid`.

The `rowid` column store 64-bit signed integer that uniquely identifies a row within the table.

Comment: Also, do `select rowid, * from table_name` to retrieve the rowid as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> Parse error: near "autoincrement": syntax error

Because I used `AUTOINCREMENT` without `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT
          -- ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
);
```

So, I used `AUTOINCREMENT` with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
  -- ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ ↑↑↑
);
```

[The doc](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html#the_autoincrement_keyword) says below:

> Any attempt to use `AUTOINCREMENT` on a WITHOUT ROWID table or on a column other than the `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column results in an error.

In addition, if you use `TEXT` type with `PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
  -- ↑↑↑↑
);
```

Then, you get the error below:

> Parse error: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score -4):

It's an easy solution. Just use `AUTOINCREMENT` instead of `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: They *are* using `AUTOINCREMENT`.