# SQLite scrolling efficiency question

Tags: sqlite

I'm writing a simple todo app for educational purposes. I store all todos in an SQLite database. Every todo has a due date. My app has a table view that displays all todos, sorted ascending by due date.

I want to implement scrolling using a [scrolling cursor](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor). For the scrolling cursor, I obviously need a column that a) has unique entries and b) whose entries are sorted by the due date.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some column like "task id" which will be an [auto-increment primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042848/error-in-near-autoincrement/4043269#4043269).

Comment: How would that column be sorted by due date though?

Comment: @user282635: Emmm. Fair. Maybe you can create a composite key using the auto-increment and the due date?

Comment: I guess I'll have to create a new "priority" column and keep track of task ordering myself...