# SQLITE Database error when creating a table with prepopulated information (Table has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied)

Tags: java, sqlite

so I am just getting into Java using Eclipse. I have written a few Minecraft plugins with it but this is my first actuall desktop program that I am writing for my local community center.

The program needs to use a database so I am going with a local database rather than a cloud based one because I am just getting into this.

I have been working for a while on the database and I can't seem to get past the following error: SQL error or missing database (table user has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied)

My code and a screenshot of the error are below.

Thanks in advance,
~Stone

[image: Error Message]

[image: Code that I believe the error is coming from]

Entire Class Below:

```
package main;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class SQLiteConnect {

private static Connection con;
private static boolean hasData = false;

public ResultSet displayUsers() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    if (con == null) {
        getConnection();
    }

    Statement state = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet res = state.executeQuery("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM user");
    return res;
}

private void getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:SQLiteConnect.db");
    initialise();
}

private void initialise() throws SQLException {

    if ( !hasData) {
        hasData = true;

        Statement state = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = state.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='user'");

        if ( !res.next() ) {
            System.out.println("Building the User table with prepopulated values.");
            //need to build the table before you can call it if it doesn't already exist
            Statement state2 = con.createStatement();
            state2.execute("CREATE TABLE user(id integer," + "firstname varchar(60)," + "lastname varchar(60)," + "primary key(id));");

            // insert sample data
            PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user values(?,?);");
            prep.setString(1,  "John");
            prep.setString(2, "McNeil");
            prep.execute();

            PreparedStatement prep2 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user values(?,?);");
            prep2.setString(1,  "Paul");
            prep2.setString(2,  "Smith");
            prep2.execute();

        }

    }
}

public void addUser (String firstname, String lastname) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    if (con == null) {
        getConnection();
    }

    PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user values(?,?);");
    prep.setString(1,  firstname);
    prep.setString(2,  lastname);
    prep.execute();

}
```

}

---------- Edit 1 ---------

Ok so I changed the code from line 43 to the following:

```
state2.execute("CREATE TABLE user(id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT," + "firstname varchar(60)," + "lastname varchar(60)," + "primary key(id));");
```

Now I get this error: "SQL error or missing database (near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error)"

I am prob just not typing it in the correct order or something

Image Below:

[image: Error #2]

Comment: Your id is missing 'autoincrement'

Comment: Do I just add 'autoincriment' behind the 'id integer'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error, as has been mentioned, arises because you are inserting into a table that has three columns but your stored procedure is only providing values for two.

You expect the database to provide the id value for you.  Your database can do that, and your stored procedure will work just fine, if you set your table up to do that.  You need to tell the database to autoincrement (using the internal *rowid* at the id value) on the USER table.  This is done as part of the database table definition by either adding INTEGER PRIMARY KEY or INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT ad the data type for the ID column.

```
state2.execute("CREATE TABLE user(id integer," + "firstname varchar(60)," + "lastname varchar(60)," + "primary key(id));");
```

should be

```
state2.execute("CREATE TABLE user(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + "firstname varchar(60)," + "lastname varchar(60)," + "primary key(id));");
```

OR

```
state2.execute("CREATE TABLE user(id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT," + "firstname varchar(60)," + "lastname varchar(60)," + "primary key(id));");
```

Comment: I posted an edit with a new error after trying your suggestion above, I also wanted to let you know that I tried to follow what they said here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042848/error-in-near-autoincrement But adding PRIMARY KEY before AUTOINCRIMENT or just removing the AUTOINCRIMENT after the PRIMARY KEY resulted in an error telling me that my table had too many Primary keys.

Answer (score 1):

The error really says it all - the table has three columns, but you're only supplying two of them when inserting. If you want to do that, you need to explicitly list the columns you're inserting.

Also, as a side note, you don't need to create another `PreparedStatement`, but can reuse the same one:

```
PreparedStatement prep = 
    con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?;");

prep.setString(1, "John");
prep.setString(2, "McNeil");
prep.executeUpdate();

prep.setString(1, "Paul");
prep.setString(2, "Smith");
prep.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Yeah I know, sorry I didn't phrase my question well enough. I really wanted: how do I change my table to either only have 2 slots (one for first name and one for last name) or would it be better/neccisary to have a slot for the ID as well? Also I thought that I was inserting three sets of information: the first name, lastname, and ID#?